# Firefox 4 quits unexpectedly running Cucumber/Capybara/Webdriver

Tags: firefox, cucumber, capybara, webdriver

I just updated to the latest Firefox (4) and now our Cucumber, Capybara and Webdriver test suite is throwing errors when it tries to launch Firefox (anything marked with @javascript).

Our test suite was running fine (and fully passing) before I upgraded to Firefox 4 yesterday.

Here are the problem details as would be reported to Apple (I'm on a Mac):

```
Process:         firefox-bin [756]
Path:            /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
Identifier:      firefox-bin
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  ruby [656]

Interval Since Last Report:          74 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           5
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  0 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   5

Date/Time:       2011-03-23 07:52:28.298 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.5.8 (9L31a)
Report Version:  6
Anonymous UUID:  8DC774A8-BD92-4645-8720-2D39B03B36AF

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  unknown required load command 0x80000022
```

I haven't been able to find any other reference of this issue online and don't know where to start with troubleshooting it...

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**: after going back to 3.6 things work again. It seems the problem is specifically with Firefox 4 (both via update and directly from the site).

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using? 2.0b3 was released just two days ago with support for Firefox 4.

Comment: 2.0b3 corresponds to version 0.1.4 of the selenium-webdriver gem. Make sure you're using that.

Comment: This looks like it might be a problem with the Firefox installation on your system.  Perhaps try moving the old Firefox out of the way and re-copying the new Firefox into /Applications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue with Firefox when launched from the command line on 10.5. It has been [reported to Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=602049), but closed as WONTFIX.

Obviously not the ideal solution, but you can work around this by stripping the x86_64 parts of the firefox-bin binary:

```
cd /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS
mv firefox-bin firefox-bin.original
ditto --arch i386 firefox-bin.original firefox-bin
```